# Is this valid C++?

Tags: c++, standards, compiler-construction

```
struct SomeStruct
{
  int a; 
  int b;
};

SomeStruct someFn( int init )
{
  SomeStruct ret = { init, init };
  //...
  return ret;
}

void someFn2( SomeStruct* pStruct )
{
  // ..
}

int main( )
{
  someFn2( &someFn(32) );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks valid to me, but why don't you compile it and find out?

Comment: It compiles fine. However, the program barfs when it's run.

Comment: Define "barfs". Can you compile with -Wall (or the equivalent on your compiler) and see if there are any warnings? How about posting the exact error messages you are getting.

Comment: @Daniel "it compiles" and "it works for me" aren't very good measures of validity.

Comment: Exactly. I was looking for a answer which cited the standard, and why something like this is disallowed. This is a proof of concept: I am not actually attempting to do this.

Comment: Evan: You should add that to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571731/is-it-possible-to-change-the-temporary-object-and-to-pass-it-as-an-argument

Comment: @Kirill V. Lyadvinsky: The question you link to isn't a strict duplicate. This question is really about what you can apply `&` (address-of) operator to, whereas the linked question is all about binding temporaries to references and doesn't involve address-of at all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, it's not valid.

From 5.2.2/10 [expr.call] "A function call is an *lvalue* if and only if  the result type is a reference.

From 5.3.1/2 [expr.unary.op] "The operand shall be an lvalue or a *qualified-id*".

`someFn(32)` is, therefore, not an *lvalue* as `SomeStruct` is not a reference and you are using it as the operand to `&` which requires an lvalue.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ g++ -Wall -o stuct struct.cc 
struct.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
struct.cc:21: warning: taking address of temporary
```

You should probably be doing:

```
int main( )
{
  SomeStruct s = someFn(32);
  someFn2(&s);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No it's not.

You can only use & on lvalues. SomeFn(32) is not a lvalue.

Your main should be like this :

```
int main( )
{
  SomeStruct s;
  s = someFn(32);
  someFn2(&s);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual idiom is to pass a const reference rather than a pointer if your function can accept  temporaries.

```
#include<iostream>

struct SomeStruct {
    int a;
    int b;

    ~SomeStruct() {
        std::cout << "SomeStruct destroyed" << std::endl;
    }
};

SomeStruct someFn ( int init )
{
    SomeStruct ret = { init, init };
    return ret;
}

void someFn2 ( SomeStruct* pStruct )
{
    std::cout << "someFn2 called" << std::endl;
}

void someFn2 ( const SomeStruct& someStruct )
{
    std::cout << "someFn2 called" << std::endl;
}

int main( )
{
    someFn2 ( &someFn ( 32 ) ); // warning - taking address of temporary
    someFn2 ( someFn ( 32 ) ); // no warning - safe in non-broken compilers
    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
someFn2 called
SomeStruct destroyed
someFn2 called
SomeStruct destroyed
```

IIRC, the set of 'non-broken' compilers does not include Visual C++ 2003 or earlier.

An example of this idiom in the stl would be:

```
string a = "red";
string b = " apple";
string c = a + b;
```

where the `std::string(const std::string&)` constructor is called for `c` with the temporary `std::string` returned from the call to `std::string::operator+` .